# How to perform Header sorting in OnDemandGrid?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

1. How to do sorting in `OnDemandGrid` with `JSONrestStore`?

   I tried `sortable:true` like below but it did not work.

   ```
    {field: "column1",label: "column1",sortable:true},
    {field: "column2",label: "column1",sortable:true}
   ```

   The normal String sorting itself is not working.
2. I also want to customize the sorting for currency fields and Date fields.

Please tell how to do customized sorting in `OndemandGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the JsonRest store and you're sorting on a column you will notice that it's actually making request to the server, your sorting needs to happen server side (SQL query or whatever you're using) with the results passed back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

listen to the 'dgrid-sort' event on the onDemandGrid instance you have created to do any kind of custom sorting

```
myGrid.on('dgrid-sort', function(grid, parentEvent, data){
  // sort data according to your custom logic
}
```

You can also progrmatically set the sort order:

```
set("sort", property, descending)
```

Reference: https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/Grid

Comment: The event dgrid-sort is not getting called,when clicking on the grid header.please give me example.

Comment: can you please post your code - that'll help in debugging it better.

Comment: What version of dgrid are you on? I only get the first (evt) object back, not parentEvent or data.